# Validação usando JS

Tags: javascript, html

boa tarde amigos !

Estou tentando fazer o meu form validar um campo pra teste, porem ele nao esta respondendo a validação de nulos por JS.

Segue o código no snippet:

```js
function Validacao() {
  if (document.form.razao_social.value == "") {
    alert("Por favor empreencha o campo");
    document.form.razao_social.focus();
    return false;

  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Cadastro Prestador</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- menu -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cadastro de Prestador</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </nav>

  <style>
    #cont1 {
      border: solid;
      margin-top: 2%;
      padding: 1%;
      padding-bottom: 2%;
    }
    
    #btn_cad {
      float: right;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function Validacao() {
      if (document.form.razao_social.value == "") {
        alert("Por favor empreencha o campo");
        document.form.razao_social.focus();
        return false;

      }
    }
  </script>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Prestador</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form name "Ficha1" action="cadastroprestador.php" onsubmit="return Validacao()" method="post">
          <div class="form-group" id="Prestador">
            <div class="col-lg-2">
              <label for="ex1">ID </label>
              <input class="form-control" name="id" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
              <label for="ex2">Razão Social</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="razao_social" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
              <label for="ex3">Nome Fantasia</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="nome_fantasia" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
              <label for="ex4">CNPJ</label>
              <input class="form-control" name="CNPJ" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
              <label for="ex6">Tipo</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
                <option>HOSPITAL</option>
                <option>CLINICA</option>
                <option>LABORATORIO</option>
                <option>REMOÇÃO</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
              <label for="ex5">Indicação</label>
              <select class="form-control" name="indicacao">
                <option>Prospecção</option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
                <option></option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Logadouro</div>
      <div class="panel-body">

        <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
          <label for="ex2">Endereço</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="endereco" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
          <label for="ex3">Numero</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="Numero" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
          <label for="ex4">Bairro</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="bairro" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
          <label for="ex6">Cidade</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="cidade" type="text">
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
          <label for="ex6">UF</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="UF" type="text">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-2 right" id="btn_cad">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.form` não acha nada porque não existe elemento com o `name` `form`. A não ser que o `name` do formulário fosse "form": `<form name="form"...`

Coloque um `this` em `onsubmit="return Validacao(this)"` e um argumento na função:

```
                   ↓
function Validacao(f){...
```

E substitua `document.form` por `f`:

```
function Validacao(f){
   if (f.razao_social.value==""){
      alert("Por favor empreencha o campo");
      f.razao_social.focus();
      return false; 
   }
}
```

> Falta também um sinal de `=` após "name" em: `<form name "Ficha1"...`

Ou então você pode pegar pelo nome do formulário, que é `Ficha1`, sem enviar o `this` para a função:

```
function Validacao(){
   if (document.Ficha1.razao_social.value==""){
      alert("Por favor empreencha o campo");
      document.Ficha1.razao_social.focus();
      return false; 
   }
}
```

A vantagem de enviar o `this` é que o código fica mais limpo e mais prático de trabalhar.

O `this` representa o próprio elemento que está chamando a função, e o `f` é um argumento da função que recebe o valor do `this`. O `f` é apenas um nome qualquer que você escolhe; poderia ser:

```
function Validacao(a){...
```

ou

```
function Validacao(formulario){...
```

ou

```
function Validacao(i){...
```

ou

```
function Validacao(x){...
```

etc.

Para melhorar a validação, use o método [.trim()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) para evitar que apenas espaços digitados passe pelo `if`:

```
if (f.razao_social.value.trim() == ""){...
```

Comment: poxa que simples hahaha, poderia me dar uma explicação breve sobre o f e sobre o this

Comment: Adicionei na pergunta. :D

Comment: muito obg pela ensinamento ficou mais claro agr, RESOLVIDO abraços 

deu certo aqui.

xD

Comment: Valeu! Quando uma resposta resolver uma pergunta, marque-a com ✔. Abs!