# Problemas com função no HTML

Tags: javascript, html

boa tarde galera tudo bem ?

Estou tentando chamar um função que fiz pra validar um campo nulo do html, porem a função nao esta chamando.

tenho um arquivo nome:
Verificacampos.js

```
function Validacao(f) {
    if (f.razao_social.value.trim == "") {
        alert("Por favor empreencha o campo");
        f.razao_social.focus();
        return false; 

        }
    }
```

e o html que nao chama a função em onsubmit:

```
<head>
<title>Cadastro Prestador</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script language"javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Verificacampos.js"></script>
</head>



<body>
<!-- menu -->

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-inverse">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Cadastro de Prestador</a>
        </div>

  </div>
 </nav>

 <style>


        #cont1{
        border: solid;
        margin-top: 2%;
        padding: 1%;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
    }

    #btn_cad{
        float: right;
    }


 </style>

<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Prestador</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form name= "Ficha1" action="cadastroprestador.php" onsubmit="return Validacao()" method="post">
            <div class="form-group" id="Prestador">
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                <label for="ex1">ID </label>
                <input class="form-control" name="id" type="text" >
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                <label for="ex2">Razão Social</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="razao_social" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex3">Nome Fantasia</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="nome_fantasia" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex4">CNPJ</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="CNPJ" type="text">
            </div>      
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex6">Tipo</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="tipo">
                            <option>HOSPITAL</option>
                            <option>CLINICA</option>
                            <option>LABORATORIO</option>
                            <option>REMOÇÃO</option>
                            </select>
            </div>  
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex5">Indicação</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="indicacao">
                        <option>Prospecção</option>
                        <option></option>
                        <option></option>
                        <option></option>
                        </select>
            </div>



      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">Logadouro</div>
      <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
                <label for="ex2">Endereço</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="endereco" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex3">Numero</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="Numero" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex4">Bairro</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="bairro" type="text">
            </div>      
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex6">Cidade</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="cidade" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 form-group">
                <label for="ex6">UF</label>
                    <input class="form-control" name="UF" type="text">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-2 right"  id="btn_cad" >Cadastrar</button>      
        </form> 
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seria melhor usar o atributo 'required' no input ao invés de usar javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Dois erros:

Faltou o `this` no:

```
 onsubmit="return Validacao(this)"
                             ↑↑
```

E os parênteses no método `.trim()`:

```
if (f.razao_social.value.trim() == "") {
                             ↑↑
```

Comment: deu certo sam obg

Comment: Quando uma resposta resolver uma pergunta, marque-a com ✔, inclusive na outra que vc fez [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/351909/8063)

Comment: Se não sabe como marcar, dá uma lida [nesta página](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

No html arquivo informe para a função o nome do FORMULÁRIO:

```
<form name= "Ficha1" action="cadastroprestador.php" onsubmit="return Validacao(Ficha1)" method="post">
```

Já no arquivo Verificacampos.js mude o trecho de código abaixo

```
if (f.razao_social.value.trim == "") {
```

para:

```
if (f.razao_social.value.trim() == "") {
```